# How to rename several variables at once to add prefix self. in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How to rename several variable at once to add prefix `self.` in Pycharm?

I tried using shift+F6 on variable but received error:
Inserted identifier is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the variable name you want to change and choose:

Refactor -> Introduce field (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>):

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/extract-field.html

You can also extract any expression by selecting it and following the same steps.